# What is the function to find a set of ordered values in a random set?

Tags: combinations

Given a set of discrete ordered values, what are the amount of combinations of n values within that set?

Such as;

Given the set [1,2,3,4,5] and choose n = 3, the total combinations are

[1,2,3]
[1,2,4]
[1,2,5]
[1,3,4]
[1,3,5]
[1,4,5]
[2,3,4]
[2,3,5]
[2,4,5]
[3,4,5]

What would the function be such as f(m, n) where m is the total count of elements.  And n is the amount to chose?

Comment: Look up "binomial coefficients".

Comment: Did you forget $\{1,3,4\}$, $\{1,3,5\}$, $\{1,4,5\}$, and $\{2,4,5\}$?

Comment: Seems like it..  Fixed for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the binomial function.  Also called the "Choose" function.

Answer (score 1):

It is
$$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$